Node.js Multer: Intermittent File Upload Failures - Files Not Uploading to Server Randomly
I am facing an intermittent issue with file uploads using Multer in my Node.js application. The issue is that files are not always being uploaded to the server, and the req.files array sometimes contains only partial information about the files.
Description of the Issue:
In my application, users upload files through a browser, which are then saved in the state in React.js. The file types can be .pdf, .jpg, .step, .stp, .iges, .stl, etc. The following code is used to handle file selection and save the files in the state:
Note: I am using React DropZone for file uploading
const onSelectFile = async (filesData, ext) => {
  try {
    setIsQuoteChanged(true);
    const filesCollection = [...files];

    for (let file of filesData) {
      const singleValue = {
        selectedFile: file,
        partFileName: file?.path || file?.name,
        ...commandFields
      };

      valueCollection.push(singleValue);

      filesCollection.push({
        ...file,
        isNotFromMongoDB: true
      });
    }

    setFiles(filesCollection);
  } catch (err) {
    //Error handling
  }
};


When it’s time to submit the form, the following code appends the files to formData and makes the API call:
const saveApiCall = (user, updateType) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
 
        let formData = new FormData();
        files.map((val, i) => {
          formData.append('selectedFile', val?.selectedFile || val)
        })

        for (const key in twoDFiles) {
          const value = twoDFiles[key];
          formData.append('twoDFiles', value?.file);
        }

        formData.append('twoDFilesData', JSON.stringify(twoDFiles))
        //other formdata appends.....

        if (_id) {
          const updateResponse = await postApi(`comman/update-quote/${_id}`, formData, token);
          return resolve(updateResponse.data);
        } else {
          const response = await postApi('comman/save-quote', formData, token);
          return resolve(response.data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        //Error handling
      }
    })
  }


//code for postApi
export const postApi = async (endPoint, payload,token) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      //code for headers

      let response = await axios.post(`${config.backEnd}/${endPoint}`, payload, { headers: header });
      return resolve(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
}


Backend Code:
Here's the backend route handling the file upload using Multer:
const multer = require('multer');
const multerIns = multer();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'public/uploads/'),
  filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname),
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post('/save-quote', multerIns.any(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // code for userdata
    const response = await CommonController.createQuote(req.body, req.files, userData.userType)
    return res.status(200).send({ status: true, message: 'save data', data: response })
  } catch (err) {
    //error handling
  }
})


Issue:
Out of 100%, the code works fine in 95% of situations. However, at certain random moments, the files data is not available in req.files. Instead of receiving the complete file information, I get:
{
  path: <File name>
}

and the files are not available on the server. This issue is intermittent and cannot be replicated at will but is occurring more frequently in production, causing significant business impact.
Environment:
Node.js version: v18.14.0
Multer version: ^1.4.5-lts.1
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Steps to Reproduce:
Set up a basic Node.js server with the above code.
Use an API client (e.g., Postman) to upload files repeatedly.
Observe that some files do not appear in the uploads/ directory.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I've Tried:
Ensured the upload directory exists and has the correct permissions.
Checked server logs for any errors (none found).
Increased the logging level to debug but still no useful information.
Questions:
What could be causing these random failures in file uploads?
Are there any known issues with Multer or its configuration that might lead to this behavior?
What additional debugging steps can I take to identify the root cause?

Make your example as minimal as possible. See what a [mre] is. I take it to be that filesData is a FileList. Do clarify that too in your [edit].

@ChukwujiobiCanon As per your suggestion I have updated the code to make it minimal also, since I am using react-dropzone which returns an array of files, not FileList. I hope this clarification helps.

Multer with FileStore:
Yes, there is something failing in the following line of code. The upload is consistent when this line is omitted. It is inconsistent when the same line is enabled, as the below code demonstrates.
  filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname),

Code showing inconsistent upload. This inconsistency is there in every run of this code.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const multerIns = multer();
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// new code to server index.html
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', router);

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'public/uploads/'),
  filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname),
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/save-quote', upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .send({ status: true, message: 'save data', data: 'some data' });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Passing formData to an API gateway
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Passing formData to an API gateway</h1>
  </body>
  <script>
    const obj = { greetings: 'Hello' };
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {
      type: 'application/json',
    });
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      formData.append(i, blob);
    }
    // uploading to the Gateway API
    fetch('/save-quote', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Error on uploading file');
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>

Test results:
Expectation : 100 files uploaded

Resulted: 
Run 1 : 5 files Uploaded 
Run 2 : 3 files Uploaded
Run 3 : 3 files Uploaded

Test results: when the following line is omitted.
// filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname),


Expectation : 100 files uploaded

Resulted: 
Run 1 : 100 files Uploaded 
Run 2 : 100 files Uploaded
Run 3 : 100 files Uploaded

Solution
It depends upon your exact requirement. As an easy solution I may propose as below. Please use the third argument to append. This would be assigned as the blob content file name. The code below does the same.
Syntax : append(name, value, filename)

for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  formData.append(i, blob, i);
}

Now on the server, the below code would do the job. Use the original file name as it is passed to append in the frontend.
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'public/uploads/'),
  filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname),
});

Test results
It gives a consistent upload.

If you observe, the developer has used the multerIns.any() in this specific route, instead of upload.any(),
If I use upload.any(), the things are a little predictable as the file first get saved in the server and we get the req.files as
{
fieldname: 'fileField1',
originalname: 'file1.txt',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'text/plain',
destination: 'public/uploads/',
filename: '1626571434982file1.txt',
path: 'public/uploads/1626571434982file1.txt',
size: 12345 // Size of the file in bytes
},

But when I user multerIns.any(), the req.file is as given below:
{
fieldname: 'fileField1',
originalname: 'file1.txt',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'text/plain',
buffer: <Buffer ...>, // Buffer containing the file data
size: 12345 // Size of the file in bytes
},
in this specific route we need the buffer data which is used in controller at later stage is also used to save file in the server using fs  module in nodejs. Can you please suggest  if you can find the any issue in the implementation using multerIns.any() ? I will update the code inside controller asap

Hi, I tried with Buffer as well. Please see the another answer posted.

Multer with MemoryStore:
Sorry, there is no such missing I could reproduce while running the code below. The code uses MemoryStore as opposed to file store in the other answer. The upload finds so consistent.
server2.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { writeFile } = require('fs/promises');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const folder = __dirname + '/public/uploads/';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', router);

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/save-quote', upload.any(), async (req, res) => {

  req.files.forEach((file) => {
    writeFile(folder + file.originalname, file.buffer).catch((err) =>
      res.send
        .status(500)
        .send({ status: false, message: 'error saving data', data: null })
    );
  });
  res
    .status(200)
    .send({ status: true, message: 'data saved successfully', data: 'some data' });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Test results:
Expectation : 100 files uploaded

Resulted: 
Run 1 : 100 files Uploaded 
Run 2 : 100 files Uploaded
Run 3 : 100 files Uploaded

index.html This file is the same mentioned in the other answer.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Passing formData to an API gateway
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Passing formData to an API gateway</h1>
  </body>
  <script>
    const obj = { greetings: 'Hello' };
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {
      type: 'application/json',
    });
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      formData.append(i, blob, i);
    }
    // uploading to the Gateway API
    fetch('/save-quote', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Error on uploading file');
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>


Thanks for the efforts, just as I mentioned that the code seems to be working fine 95% of times. But at very random times it will not save the file in server which is causing a lot of issue for me to handle this issue. So far, I am unable to replicate this issue in my local machine. Is it possible that there might be some issue related to network or same other random stuff instead of code?

If the end users are accessible to you and they can provide you feedback, then it may be help if you develop a checking routine as well. It means once the upload is done, this routine should ensure that the upload has not missed anything. This should rely on a custom logic whatever can apply as per your thoughts and situation.  This routine may be required only for some time till the corner issue is spotted. The relevance of this routine may be that the so called "missing" may be happening only when the module is operated in a particular sequence, or particular files, or particular users etc.

second option may be : Honouring the warning from Multer and refactor the code without using memory storage: WARNING: Uploading very large files, or relatively small files in large numbers very quickly, can cause your application to run out of memory when memory storage is used. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answering to your question, networks issues or random stuff - such items are always there with any applications. We have been seeing, it has been well taken care by the lower layer softwares. An application consuming these layers is not suppose to worry about it, this you know very well. My own view and opinion is to be open to adopt any implementation which gives sturdy performance. I mean to say, if Multer has some other stable ways to get the job done, please adopt it.

Thank you for the detailed analysis; it’s been very helpful. Currently, I store the files in Firebase Storage from the front end to create a backup (with proper security rules and authentication). Whenever this issue occurs, I upload these files to the server. The files appear to be available on the front end, but it seems something goes wrong during the transfer from the front end to the backend. Based on your information, I will update the code to see if it resolves the issue. Thanks again for your time and effort—it’s been a great help.

Thank you for your feedback. May it be a success.

Hi, if possible, please see this QA adds value to your development. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78769103/multer-error-is-not-sent-in-response-request-keeps-pending

Thanks for the link. I will check if out and if this issue is resolved, I will definitely update here.
